# Riemannian metrics on square

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $V\subset\mathbb R^2$ be the square with $|u|<1$ and $|v|<1$. Define two Riemannian metrics on $V$ given by
$$\frac{du^2}{(1-u^2)^2}+\frac{dv^2}{(1-v^2)^2}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{du^2}{(1-v^2)^2}+\frac{dv^2}{(1-u^2)^2}.$$
Prove that there is no isometry between the two spaces, but that an area preserving diffeomorphism does exist.

As a hint, I have been told that in one space, there are curves of finite length going to the boundary, but not in the other space, which would show that they are not isometric. However, I'm not sure how to write down a formal mathematical statement to apply the hint.

I know that the length of a curve $\gamma(t)=(u(t),v(t))$, say $\gamma:(0,1)\to\mathbb R^2$ is
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{(u')^2}{(1-u^2)^2}+\frac{(v')^2}{(1-v^2)^2}}\;dt$$
for the first space, and something analogous for the second space, but I'm not sure where to go.

[This is Exercise 4.6 in P M H Wilson's *Curved Spaces*].

Comment: In the second metric, horizontal segments (and vertical segments) have bounded length, and these segments "escape from" every compact subset of the square (i.e., if $K$ is compact, "every horizontal segment sticks out of $K$ at the ends"). If a diffeomorphism of the square were an isometry with the first metric, then a horizontal segment would map to a curve escaping from every compact subset of the square. But no such curve has bounded length in the first metric. [...]

Comment: Alternatively, you might show the metrics do not have the same Gaussian curvature, while they do have the same area element.